# Parsing JSON for GOOGLE API Returning Images iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

Just wondering if I am doing this correctly, It seems a lot of code for something so simple...

Passing the google json request with my key to this function using ASIHTTPREQUEST

```
        NSString *url4Google = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=(MY SECRET KEY)&country=GB&q=5035822086234"];

        ASIHTTPRequest* request = [self requestWithURL:url4Google];
```

Code for processing...

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request {

NSLog(@"GOOGLE SHOPPER IMAGE LOADING");

NSDictionary *result = [[request responseString] objectFromJSONString];

//GOOGLE SHOPPER IMAGE RETURN..

NSArray *Image = [[[[result objectForKey:@"items"] valueForKey:@"product"] valueForKey:@"images"] valueForKey:@"link"] ;

NSArray *Title = [[[result objectForKey:@"items"] valueForKey:@"product"] valueForKey:@"title"];

//NSLog(@"TITLE OF ITEM = %@", Title);

int size = [Image count];
NSLog(@"there are %d product images for this barcode ", size);

int titlez = [Title count];
NSLog(@"there are %d title names for this barcode ", titlez);

NSArray *imagearray = [Image objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *titleofitemis = [Title objectAtIndex:2];

//Choosing a number objectAtIndex...

NSMutableString * result1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSObject * obj in imagearray)
{
    [result1 appendString:[obj description]];
}
NSLog(@"FULL IMAGE URL IS = %@", result1);

//SET IMAGE
 NSURL* _url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:result1];
 self.url = _url;
 [_url release];
[result1 release];

 NSLog(@"url = %@", url);

 UIImage* image = [ImageManager loadImage:url];
 if (image) {
 imageView.image = image;
 }    

//SET TITLE
self.title = titleofitemis;

NSLog(@"FULL TITLE NAME IS = %@", titleofitemis);
}
```

I am using SBJSON and also ImageManager to async load the image after it has located an image..

I have done a bit of memory management as for me that isn't too much of a problem for this example...

NSLOG OUTPUT

```
2011-09-28 16:29:17.351 IOSBoilerplate[17906:11c03] done pressed
2011-09-28 16:29:18.031 IOSBoilerplate[17906:11c03] GOOGLE SHOPPER IMAGE LOADING
2011-09-28 16:29:18.034 IOSBoilerplate[17906:11c03] there are 25 product images for this     barcode 
2011-09-28 16:29:18.035 IOSBoilerplate[17906:11c03] FULL URL FOR IMAGE = http://static.gam.co/media/films/00/000/0032/32467/image/30403.jpg
```

Is this the quickest way & has this been done right, I can do all error level detection later..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good. Some cleanup / style suggestions:

```
//...
NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString string]; // shorter, autoreleased
for (NSString *s in imagearray) { // already typed
   [urlString append:s];
}
self.url = [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];    // that's all it takes
UIImage *displayImage = [ImageManager loadImage:url];
// code is very readable, too
```

Please refrain from using instance names starting with a capital letter, such as your `Image` or `Title`. The convention is that capitalized names are used for classes, not instances. Also, more descriptive names such as `imageArray` or `imageList` makes the code much more understandable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and looking at my code Mundi, I have been an ios developer now for a year and a half and I have always used caps, i think its just a part of habit now!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Google's [Objective-C API library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) with the Shopping API. The library handles networking and authentication, and returns results as first-class Objective-C objects.  The library includes a [sample application for Shopping](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/ShoppingSample/ShoppingSampleWindowController.m) as well.